# Chain rule with respect to vector

Tags: calculus, vectors, chain-rule

I am tring to find this derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{w}} (\frac{1}{2}(t-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{o})^2)
$$

Where the $\mathbf{w}$, $\mathbf{o} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are column vectors.

From the chain rule and this property $ \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}} (\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{b}) = \mathbf{b} $ I believe that the derivative should be:

$$
(t-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{o})(-\mathbf{o})
$$

---

In detail:

$$
f(\mathbf{w}) = \frac{1}{2} g(\mathbf{w})^2 \\
g(\mathbf{w}) = t-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{o} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_i} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial w_i} = (t-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{o})(-o_i) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{w}} = (t-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{o})(-\mathbf{o})
$$

---

But then I see a problem with distributivity, because I get:

$$
\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{o}\mathbf{o} + t\mathbf{o}
$$

so for the first term there is a problem with the $(\mathbf{o}\mathbf{o})$ as I am multiplying two matrices with the shape $n \times 1$.

Therefore I assumed that this derivative is wrong. Could you please give me the correct result with step-by-step solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}(w^Tb) = b$ is fully correct. Rather
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}(w^Tb) = \frac{\partial}{\partial w}(b^Tw) = b^T$$
Using this you get
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial w} = (t - w^To)(-o^T) = -to^T + w^Too^T $$
and there's no problem with multiplying $oo^T$.

Still, it should be noted that $(w^To)o$ can have a well-defined matematical sense, even if $w^T(oo)$ doesn't; that's because in $(w^To)o$ you can identify $\mathbb M_{1\times 1}(\mathbb R)\equiv \mathbb R$, and you have a multiplication $\mathbb R  \times\mathbb M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb R) \to M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb R)$ even if you don't have a multiplication $M_{1\times 1}(\mathbb R) \times M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb R) \to M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb R) $. Still again, you can make use of a tensor product and write
$$(w^To)o = w^T(o \otimes o)$$
where it needs to be understood that the contraction of $w^T$ with $o\otimes o$ is at the first component.

Comment: Whether $\partial(w^Tb)/\partial w$ equals $b$ or $b^T$ depends on the convention: numerator and denominator layouts have different opinions on whether the derivative of a scalar w.r.t. a column should be a row or a column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have marked it as accepted. Let mu just ask you what you mean by: contraction of $w^T$ with $o⊗o$ is at the first component.

Comment: I mean that if $(e_i)$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$, the components of relevant tensors in appropriate bases are $$(w^T)_i=w_i$$ $$(o\otimes o)_{ij} = o_io_j $$, and $$\big(w^T(o\otimes o)\big)_j = \sum_iw_i(o \otimes o)_{ij}= \sum_iw_io_io_j$$ In the last formula there's the contraction over the index $i$, which is related to the first component of product $o\otimes o$.

Answer (score 1):

In my answer I skip the bold style for vectors.
Assuming that $\displaystyle\frac {\partial o}{\partial w } = 0$ and $t\in \mathbb R$:

$$
\frac\partial {\partial w} \left[\frac12 (t-w^{\mathsf T}o)^2\right] = 
\frac\partial {\partial w} \frac12\left[ t^2-2t\,w^{\mathsf T}o+(w^{\mathsf T}o)^2\right] = -to + (w^{\mathsf T}o) o = (-t + w^{\mathsf T}o) o = (t -w^{\mathsf T}o)(-o)
$$

PS.
In your question you wrote about problem with $oo$. I think that this is not the case since the first vector is dotted with the $w$ and produces a scalar.